# Formula to generate unique sequential IDs for items in a column that don't already have IDs

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am cataloging items in a spreadsheet using Google Sheets. Every item needs a unique ID, which is a sequential code formatted like ABxxxxxx, where AB000000 < ABxxxxxx < AB999999, starting from AB000001, AB000002, AB000003, etc., and counting up to AB999999.

Some items in my sheet already have unique IDs, but many do not. I am trying to find a formula that generates an ID, and checks if the ID is already in a specific column.

If the new ID is *not* already in the column, then that ID becomes the new, unique ID for the item; otherwise, if the ID *is* already in the column, generate a new sequential ID, and check again to see if that one is already in the column.

I believe that I can see if the ID is already in the column by using the '''IF''' and '''COUNTIF''' formulas, and I can check to see if a value is unique using the '''UNIQUE''' formula.

However, I cannot seem to find a formula that will generate a new, unique ID for every item in a column which doesn't already have an ID. Attached is a screenshot which hopefully can illustrate what I want my formula to do.

Is this even possible in Sheets?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the sequential IDs with this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula("AB"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A)),"000000"))
```

[image]

Then, you can set a filtered range, excluding those values already existing in your range:

```
=LET(ids,ArrayFormula("AB"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A)),"000000")),FILTER(ids,BYROW(ids,LAMBDA(each,ISNA(XMATCH(each,A2:A))))))
```

[image]

And, finally you can use BYROW to state that if A column has a value, use that value and if it hasn't it scans with INDEX through that filtered range (ROW(each)-COUNTA(A2:each)-1) is used to calculate how much does it need to progress)

```
=LET(ids,ArrayFormula("AB"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A)),"000000")),filt,FILTER(ids,BYROW(ids,LAMBDA(each,ISNA(XMATCH(each,A2:A))))),
 BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each<>"",each,INDEX(filt,ROW(each)-COUNTA(A2:each)-1)))))
```

[image]

Use only the last column, it was just explaining my thinking! Possibly there are other ways to do it with SORT and MATCH

Comment: Great solution.  Suggestion to simplify `'FILTER(ids, BYROW(ids, LAMBDA(each, ISNA(XMATCH(each, A2:A)))))'` down to `'FILTER(ids, ISNA(MATCH(ids, A2:A, 0)))'`

Comment: Thank you very much, Martín, that solved my problem!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful!! (and yes, @BlindSpots surely that works! I was doing something else and kept BYROW)